# Need only time, error while removing date

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#clock')[0].innerHTML = moment().format("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>");
    clock_tick();
});
function clock_tick(){
    var clock_div = $('#clock')[0];
    var time = moment(clock_div.innerHTML);
    time.add('second', 1);
    clock_div.innerHTML = time.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    setTimeout("clock_tick()", 1000);
}
</script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

I need to remove the date from this script, only need time.
I get an "Invalid Date" error

Code Courtesy Stackoverflow

Comment: you want only 11:00:00 like this?

Comment: Well you are trying to read the current time from the div so of course it will complain about an invalid date. Have you considered putting your current datetime into a variable and just use the div for display?

Comment: Turns out you don't even need a (global) variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var time = moment().format("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); ?>");

$(function () {
    $('#clock')[0].innerHTML = time;
    clock_tick();
});

function clock_tick() {
    var clock_div = $('#clock')[0];
    time = moment(time);
    time.add('second', 1);
    clock_div.innerHTML = time.format("hh:mm:ss");
    setTimeout("clock_tick()", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to emit the initial datetime from php - just use `new Date()` and you could rely on your setTimeout unless you need a high-precision clock.

Using `.toLocaleTimeString()` will even allow you to cater for specific time formats (AM/PM vs 24h).

```js
$(function () {
    clock_tick();
});

function clock_tick() {
    // just get the current DateTime
    time = new Date();

    // let a builtin function take care of the output formatting
    $('#clock').html(time.toLocaleTimeString("hi-IN"));

    // your timeout controls the elapsed second
    setTimeout("clock_tick()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```